# Change a absolute URL to relative URL use system API quick and clean?

Tags: ios, nsurl, nsurlrequest

Can I use the system API to quickly do this job?
I know I can use `regex` or combination `path` and `query` manually.
I know `NSURLComponents`，but can it change an absolute URL to a relative one?

I'm just curious, can we use the system API to do this quickly and clean?

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLComponents_class/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I use the follow snippet:

```
NSURL *url;

NSURLComponents *urlComponents = [NSURLComponents componentsWithURL:url resolvingAgainstBaseURL:NO];
urlComponents.scheme = nil;
urlComponents.host = nil;

NSURL *relativeURL = urlComponents.URL;
```